# Unable to obtain Microsoft Graph OAuth access token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started#use-oauth2-to-authenticate) documentation to get an access token to call Graph APIs for Outlook Calendar. I've registered my app on [Azure AD admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com), created a client secret and exposed relevant APIs. The app is configured for multi-tenant access and I'm using OAuth v2.0 endpoints for authorization.

I can successfully get the authorization code but get this error when requesting an access token:

```
"error": "invalid_client",

"error_description": "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.",

"error_codes": [

    7000215

],
```

I send urlencoded client secret with the access token request, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: Could you show how you are acquiring the token?

Comment: @juunas Here is the url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<my_client_id>&redirect_uri=<uriencoded_url>&response_type=code&scope=openid+offline_access+Calendars.Read

Comment: And what does the request for the access token look like?

Comment: Did you have a try with creating a new client secret? And please provide your request for the access token.

Comment: Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token with form-urlencoded parameters:
client_id: <my_client_id>
client_secret: <urlencoded_client_secret>
code: <access_code>
redirect_uri: <uri>
grant_type: authorization_code
scope: openid+offline_access+Calendars.Read

Comment: @AllenWu yes, I tried changing the client secret

Comment: @AllenWu  I also changed the accessTokenAcceptedVersion attribute in the application manifest to 2 (default was null), if that matters

Comment: Why did you urlencode the client_secret?

Comment: @AllenWu plain secret didn't work at first and the second doc I've referred to in the question says it should be urlencoded. It works now. Does this have anything to do with the endpoint version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided an invalid client secret.

Just copy it from Azure AD app and paste it into your request. There is no need to url encode it.